# Difference between calling a bash script from the commandline and executing it via python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I'm currently working on automating some processes via Django. For this purpose I have a shell script, that performs certain tasks for me. My webinterface has a "Start Process"-Button and a "Stop Process"-Button.

I came up with the idea to use the process id of the shell script to kill the process when I want to abort it. My `start.sh` looks like this:

```sh
pid=$$; 
source ./stop.sh || true
echo $pid > "./processid.txt"; 
#do the actual stuff
```

And my `stop.sh` looks like this:

```sh
pid=$(head -n 1 ./processid.txt)
kill $pid
```

What this does, it takes the process id and temporarily stores it in a variable, then stops the script, if before the script had be running, and then saves the process id to the `processid.txt` file. My stop.sh just takes this id out of the file and kills the process.

This does work from the commandline... however it doesn't when I execute it from my python code. I call it like this:

```py
def start_bot():
    popencommand = "sh -c \"cd ~/thetargetfolder && ./start.sh\"" 

    Popen(popencommand, shell=True)

def stop_bot():
    popencommand = "sh -c \"cd ~/thetargetfolder && ./stop.sh\""

    Popen(popencommand, shell=True)
```

For some reason, this doesn't seem to work. I suspect it has something to do with that the process id that I get in the `start.sh` is not the correct one when calling the python script...

Comment: You're missing a `\"` at the end of your start line.

Comment: Oh yeah, I made a mistake when copying the code, thanks ^^

Comment: Do you see `processid.txt` change when you launch this?  And by the way, specifying `shell=True` is exactly the same as prefixing the command with `sh -c`.  You might try `popencommand = "cd ~/thetargetfolder ^^ ./start.sh"`.

Comment: Also *who* does python (in Django) run it as - is `~/thetargetfolder` the same `/home/yourhome/thetargetfolder` or is it `/home/djangoUser/thetargetfolder/` or something else...

Comment: No, the start/stop.sh is from a separate project, that has nothing to do with django. Atm it's just located anywhere else, on my production instance it will also be separated.

Comment: Yes @TimRoberts it does change. It just seems to not be the correct processid, when I try to kill it it says "No such process" and also the script keeps running...

Comment: Are they all running as the same user?  Perhaps you should use a `/var/run` location instead of basing it on $HOME.

Comment: Yes, they will all be running as the same user, that's not an issue. I think the isse comes from the process being taken when executing "pid=$$" is the python process, not the actual shell process, but I don't know how to fix this issue

Comment: Note that it's generally a bad idea to have a script without a shebang. If you failed trying to start your script from Python _without_ `shell=True`, the lack of a `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` is one possible explanation as to why.

Comment: Even though I have `shell=True`  in all of my Popen's, I still added it for good measure. Unfortunately this doesn't change anything with the actual problem...

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen(['./start.sh'], cwd='/home/djangoUser/thetargetfolder')` instead.

Comment: Right now, when (thanks to the `shell=True`) you run `['sh', '-c', 'cd /path && ./yourscript']`, _indeed_ the process id doesn't match your script -- it matches the copy of `sh`, not the copy of `yourscript`. But when you use `shell=False`, there's no `sh` to get in the way.

Comment: ...so, if you have the same problem with `shell=False`, at _that_ point it's a problem with `./yourscript`, not with how it's called. (Make sure when it starts django at the end of the script, it uses `exec` to let django _replace_ the shell as owning the PID).

Comment: Also, it reduces the number of potential surprises if you switch to using `subprocess.call()` instead of just creating an unreferenced `Popen` object.

Comment: Also -- have you considered using systemd (or whatever service management tools your operating system ships with) instead of trying to reinvent the wheel in the first place? `systemctl start yourprogram` and `systemctl stop yourprogram` is a lot simpler.

Comment: (BTW, in my answer, I dropped the `.sh` extensions from the sample filenames; see [Commandname Extensions Considered Harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/) -- which while yes, it's a friend's personal website, has been considered a canonical link on the subject by the freenode #bash channel for years; history of their factoid on the subject @ http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `subprocess.Popen("sh -c 'cd /somewhere && ./whatever'", shell=True)`, you're telling Python to kick off a chain of events that runs *three* processes:

- First, because `shell=True` makes Python run `sh -c '...yourcode...'`, it starts a first copy of `sh` requested by the `shell=True`
- That first copy of `sh` runs the code `sh -c 'cd /somewhere && ./whatever'`, because that's the string you gave Python, so it then starts a *second* copy of `sh`.
- That second copy of `sh` runs `cd /somewhere && ./whatever`. If `./whatever` is a shell script, that means it starts a *third* shell.

This is a lot of unnecessary complexity! There's no reason to have more than *one* shell -- the one that runs `./whatever`, invoked by the operating system based on its shebang (`#!/bin/sh`, or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, or so forth).

---

Some of this you can eliminate by dropping down to only having *one* shell, the run that runs your scripts. Make sure the scripts have valid shebangs (`#!/usr/bin/env bash` or similar) and are executable (`chmod +x start stop`).

```
def start_bot():
    subprocess.call(
      [os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~/thetargetfolder'), './start')],
      cwd=os.path.expanduser('~/thetargetfolder')
    )

def stop_bot():
    subprocess.call(
      [os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~/thetargetfolder'), './stop')],
      cwd=os.path.expanduser('~/thetargetfolder')
    )
```

---

Finally, you can do *even better* by not using a shell for this at all, but just writing your logic directly in Python, or (even better than that!) relying on your operating system's process supervisor (most modern Linux distros ship systemd for the purpose; whereas MacOS ships with launchd). If you define `yourprogram.service`, then `systemctl start yourprogram` starts the script running, and `systemctl stop yourprogram` kills it -- and you can configure it to automatically start on boot, or on a timer, or whenever any program connects to a preopened socket, or otherwise however you like.

Comment: Python keeps not finding my file... I get a FileNotFoundException, when I execute this with the proper path: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/start'`. To make it work, I have to add `shell=True` once again ^^'

Comment: Maybe you should consider subprocess.call(os.path.expanduser('~/thetargetfolder/start'), cwd=os.path.expanduser('~/thetargetfolder')) ?

Comment: @monamoma, I'd need to see your _exact_ code to diagnose the problem. Zilog80's suggestion is a good one -- or just pass an absolute path to your program instead of using `./` in the first place.

Comment: @monamoma, ... I've modified the answer to calculate and pass an absolute path.

Comment: Fixed it... I missed a `.` in front of the `/start`...

Comment: Wen properly reading, this solved all my problems, so a very well deserved bounty. Thank you!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, it seems we've both missed to read carefully the err msg `No such file or directory: '/start'`... ^^